# How does ShaderToy load sounds into a texture

Tags: javascript, audio, three.js, webgl

I've been trying to do the same things shadertoy does for passing audio frequency/waveform into the shader with three.js.

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Xds3Rr

In this example it seems that IQ is putting frequency/waveform audio data into an image and then sampling that as a texture in the shader. How would I create that audio texture in Javascript?

To be clear I don't need help loading the texture uniform into the shader. I just don't know how to create the audio texture from an audio file.

```
var texture = new THREE.Texture();

shader.uniforms = {
     iChannel0:  { type: 't', value: texture }
};
```

I'm guessing I'll need to somehow put audio data into the texture I just don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get audio data from the Web Audio API be creating an analyser node

```
const audioContext = new window.AudioContext();
const analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
```

Then create a buffer to receive teh data

```
const numSamples = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
const audioData = new Uint8Array(numSamples);
```

Then in your render loop get the data and put it in a texture

```
analyser.getByteFrequencyData(audioData);
...
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.LUMINANCE, numSamples, 1, 0,
              gl.LUMINANCE, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, audioData);
```

or in three.js use a `DataTexture`

That's the short version. The longer version is audio needs to be on the same domain or you'll run into CORS issues. To get data for an audio stream like an `<audio>` tag's you'd call

```
const source = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audio);
```

That doesn't work in mobile Chrome nor mobile Safari at the moment and there are bugs in Safari.

[Here's a working sample](http://twgljs.org/examples/dynamic-buffers.html)

Comment: Do you have an example of how to use three.js `DataTexture` - specifically how to insert an `Uint8Array` and what parameters to use? (Uint8Array obtained from the audio analyzer in my case). https://threejs.org/docs/api/textures/DataTexture.html lists a range of parameters.