# Are textures the only way to transfer audio data into GLSL?

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl

I came across an article where a developer is building a music visualizer with shader programming. He transfers audio information to glsl via textures.  https://noisehack.com/build-music-visualizer-web-audio-api/

```
function copyAudioDataToTexture(gl, audioData, textureArray) {
  for (let i = 0; i < audioData.length; i++) {
    textureArray[4 * i + 0] = audioData[i] // R
    textureArray[4 * i + 1] = audioData[i] // G
    textureArray[4 * i + 2] = audioData[i] // B
    textureArray[4 * i + 3] = 255          // A
  }
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, audioData.length, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureArray)
}
```

I also noticed [shadertoy does a similar thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631836/how-does-shadertoy-load-sounds-into-a-texture).

I was wondering, is data in general only submitted via textures, are there other ways to channel data into glsl, maybe as vertices or something else?

Edit: I noticed there's a thing called a 'uniform' maybe I can inject audio data into that?

Comment: It sounds like you're new to webgl. Might I suggest [some tutorials](https://webglfundamentals.org)

Comment: @gman thanks will check that out. I've been especially interested in shaders. shadertoy.com has been very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with it. For visualizing data, textures are a fairly natural choice because your fragment shader (the program that actually colors individual pixels) can access data from arbitrary positions in the texture, and you even get interpolation between data points for free. This is real handy for coloring pixels on your screen as a means of visualizing your data. In this example, he's passing the spectrum data (intensity vs. frequency) in as a texture, multiplying that by the output color to make the image dark where for audio frequencies which are not part of the spectrum.

A vertex buffer wouldn't be a good way to pass in the data in this case, because AFAIK the fragment shader can't read from a vertex buffer.

Uniform is just a method of receiving global data in the shader program, like if you were to pass in a texture to be used to color or transform an image. The author is using it to pass in the texture, via the `uniform sampler2D spectrum` in his fragment shader.

If textures don't make sense for you because you want to use the GPU for something other than visualization, then you might want to consider using something like OpenCL or DirectCompute, which are designed for doing arbitrary computations.

(btw, HLSL is not being used in that example, as HLSL is the language used in Direct3D. The author is using GLSL.)

Comment: so I guess he was using a uniform after all. but weird that he used a texture (sampler2d). couldn't have just sent an array via the uniform?

Comment: Probably the reason is that you can sample from a texture at arbitrary points (think floating point coordinates), so he doesn't need to worry that his output image matches the dimensions of his input image. With an array you can only read from an integral position.

Comment: [The largest uniform array](https://webglstats.com/webgl/parameter/MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS) you can have is much much smaller than [the largest texture](https://webglstats.com/webgl/parameter/MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE).

Comment: wow a significant percentage of current hardware only allows a uniform array size of 64, I had no idea.